# What is the proper name for accessing an object property by string?

Tags: php, oop

I've been searching for quite a while and cannot find what this method is actually *called*.

In PHP example:

```
$var->{'property_name'}
```

Comment: I'm gonna go with variable variable http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: How about Complex (Curly) Syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you are accessing it will be called...

- A `variable variable`
- A `variable property`
- A `variable function`

It is worth noting that the curly-braces are only needed when you need to disambiguate an expression (bear in mind the string you use may itself be stored in a variable!)

And so on. This is documented in the [PHP manual for variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).